# Is this an automorphism over a cyclic group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, cyclic-groups

> **Problem**:
>
> If $a, b \in G$ are generators of a group $G$, then there is an automorphism $f:G\to G$ such that $f(a)=b$.

Since $G=\langle a \rangle$ and $b\in G$, I proposed that $f$ be given by: $$ f(g)=g^t, \text{where } t\in\mathbb{Z} \text{ is the integer such that }a^t=b$$

This is an homomorphism, but I'm not sure if is injective and surjective since I have not been able to prove it so far.

Is this really an isomorphism? If it is, can you give me some hints to prove it please?

**Edit#1:**
I already managed to solve the surjectivity part. Here is my attempt to prove injectivity.

> Let $x \in \ker f$, this is $e=f(x)=x^t$
>
> Since $G=\langle a \rangle$ and $x\in G$, there is a $k\in \mathbb Z$ such that $x=a^k$. Then, $e=x^t=(a^k)^t=(a^t)^k=b^k$.
>
> Here I consider two different cases. If $G$ is infinite, since $G=\langle b \rangle$ all powers of $b$ must be different, therefore given that $e=b^k$ we have $k=0$. Consequently $x=a^k=a^0=e$.
>
> If $G$ is finite, let's suppose $|G|=n$. Since $a$ and $b$ are generators, the order of both elements is $n$. From $b^k=e$ we have that $n$ divides $k$, this is, $k=nk'$. Therefore, $x=a^k=a^{nk'}=(a^n)^{k'}=e^{k'}=e$.

Is this correct? If so, do you think there is a more direct argument to prove it?

Comment: Well, if it weren't injective, say, then there would be a non-trivial element with $f(h)=e$.  What could you then say about $h$?

Comment: $h$ has finite order?

Comment: Should I treat this in cases, when $G$ is finite and when is infinite?

Comment: Well, what can you say about the order of $h$?  Is it a possible order?

Comment: I see that the order of $h$ must divide $t$, but I don't see contradictions with that...

Comment: You are missing a key point.  What do you know about $t$?

Comment: @lulu I edited the post. Was that what you meant?

Comment: No....it isn't true that the order of the group divides the order of each element (the opposite is true).  My point was that your exponent $t$ must be relatively prime to the order of the group (else the image of a generator would not be a generator). Thus an element of the kernel would have an order which was prime to the order of the group and that is not possible.

Comment: The property I was using is: If $a\in G$ is an element of order $n$ and $a^m=e$ then $n$ divides $m$.

Comment: I see. Fair enough.  Though, really, all you need is the relative primality between $t$ and $n$.

Comment: Well, I still don't see it that clear. Can you state that property, omitting the details of this particular case, please?

Comment: Which part is unclear?  $\gcd(t,n)=1$?  Well, say $\gcd(t,n)=d>1$ and write $n=dN,t=dT$ for $N,T<n$.  Then $b=g^t=g^{dT}\implies b^N=g^{dNT}=g^{nT}=e$ so the order of $b$ is less than or equal to $N$ hence $b$ could not be a generator.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a roadmap:

- If $G=\langle a \rangle$ and $b \in G$, then there is an homomorphism $f:G\to G$ such that $f(a)=b$.
- The image of $f$ is $\langle b \rangle$.
- If $G=\langle b \rangle$, then $f$ is injective.

For the last step, you need to consider the two cases: $G$ finite and $G$ infinite.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the post and the solution I proposed is based on your answer. Can you check if is correct, please?

Comment: @Карпатський, add your solution as a separate answer.

Comment: @Карпатський, when $G$ is finite, injectivity follows from surjectivity.